# Unable to install peakutils from pycharm

Tags: pycharm, installation, peakutils

I am using python 2.7 and want to install PeakUtils. I can't install the module from Pycharm.

**The Error message** is Non-zero exit code (1).

**Proposed solution**

Try to run this command from the system terminal. Make sure that you use the correct version of 'pip' installed for your Python interpreter located at '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7'.

**Command Output**

Collecting PeakUtils==1.3.0
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/peakutils/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590) - skipping

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PeakUtils==1.3.0 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for PeakUtils==1.3.0

Comment: Did you try `pip install PeakUtils` in the Terminal (not console) of Pycharm?
https://pypi.org/project/PeakUtils/
In `Settings -> Tools -> Terminal` is the Shell path correctly set up?

Comment: I can installed PeakUtils through Terminal. But I can't import PeakUtils test code in pycharm after installed PeakUtils through Terminal.